# APScheduler - ImportError: No module named 'apscheduler'

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, apscheduler

I don't know why I get this error: `ImportError: No module named 'apscheduler'`.

I tried to install the older version with:
`sudo pip uninstall apscheduler` and then `sudo pip install apscheduler==2.1.2` but this doesn't worked for me.

Here's my code:

```
import os ,subprocess
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler



def scheduled_job():
    sync_to_drive=subprocess.check_output(["./gdrive", "sync", "upload", "--keep-local", "/home/pi/Documents"], cwd="/home/pi/Downloads") 
    print (sync_to_drive)

sched = BlockingScheduler()
sched.add_job(scheduled_job, "interval", seconds=5)
sched.start()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I see python-3.x tag in your question, so you might be using python3, try `pip3 install apscheduler` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

you should use

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
```

,this is the code from new version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **anaconda** use this to install apscheduler

```
conda install -c conda-forge apscheduler

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 apscheduler
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall apscheduler and then install it again. Will fix.